# Redirect active configuration file for Google Cloud Computing

Tags: powershell, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to fully automate with the Gcloud Powershell Module but Before i can run the cmdlets i need to run gcloud-commands to store the GCloud service account information in %APPDATA%. I would like to know if anyone knows if there is a way to redirect this Active configuration file to somewhere else in the filesystem. I dont want to rely on the profile. And its easier to check for this file if its somewhere else.

Also would like to know if anyone have succedeed to authenticate against their REST API for GOogle compute (which needs creds). If so, code that can be shared. because i cannot find any information at all on this. Only .NET code which is to Deep level for me.

If i just had an example how to execute the REST API from powershell with authentication in some way i could continue with that instead of the powershell way.

Anyone with experience in these areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Cloud SDK's config directory by setting `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` to a directory of your choosing.

Older release Gcloud powershell cmdlets might not be able to respect this environment variable and still look at old location.